# Is this submonoid of the isometry group on $\Bbb Q_2$ closed to inverses?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-groups, p-adic-numbers

Let $\textrm{aff}(ax+b)$ be the affine group on $\Bbb Z_2^\times$

i.e. the set of linear polynomials over 2-adic numbers with $a\in\Bbb Z_2^\times, b\in\Bbb Z_2$

Now let $X$ be the restriction of its set to the $ax+b\cdot2^t$ where $t$ is picked such that such that $2^{\nu_2(x)}=2^{\nu_2(b\cdot2^t)}$. Let's call this $\textrm{aff}(ax+b)/\langle2\rangle$

Then for any given $a,b$ each $x$ has a single orbit through $X$ given by $f_{a,b}(x)=ax+b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ where $b$ is a 2-adic unit.

It turns out, if you sum the 2-adic values of any given orbit of $f_{a,b}(x)$, starting at $x$, you get an isometry on $\Bbb Q_2$.  This is defined algebraically as follows:

Let $f_{a,b}^n(x)$ indicate the $n^{th}$ composition of $f_{a,b}(x)$.

Then $T_{a,b}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{\textstyle{\nu_2(f_{a,b}^n(x))}}$

$T_{a,b}(x)$ is a member of the isometry group on $\Bbb Q_2$ and it is the member which topologically conjugates $ax+b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ to $x-2^{\nu_2(x)}$.  It acts by composition on $\Bbb Q_2$ and by conjugation on $X=\textrm{aff}(ax+b)/\langle2\rangle$

**Question**

I'm struggling at the moment to determine the closure as a group of the transformations $T_{a,b}(x)$ with composition as the group operation - is the monoid closed (as a group) as it is (i.e. with $(\{T_{a,b}(x):a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times\},\circ)$), or must it generate further elements?  In particular under inverses.

> For each pair $a_1,b_1$ is there an $a_2,b_2$ such that $T^{-1}_{a_2,b_2}(x)=T_{a_1,b_1}(x)$? If so, how do I get the $a_2,b_2$ representing the inverse of $a_1,b_1$?

Additionally I don't know if the restriction I give, or the isometries $\{T_{a,b}(x):a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times\}$ derived from it, have a formal terminology name or identity.  If you can identify any of these objects for me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455325/is-f-a-bx-ax-b-cdot2-nu-2x-a-b-in-bbb-z-2-times-a-subgroup-of-t#comment1178773_455325), I did not downvote, but this question is unlikely to get much in the way of careful reading, because it doesn't give many pointers to navigating a very long post.  Could you give some clues for people who want to find the question quickly? (The best would be to move the question as early as it can sensibly be stated, and give motivation after.) For example, "do these generate a group?" in the title is puzzling, because every subset of a group generates a group.

Comment: @LSpice thank-you for your help.  "is it a group or does it generate one?" is intended to mean "are there elements other than the generators I give?" Is there a better way of saying that? It is long, but I think I have made it VERY easy to read and follow rather than succinct.

Comment: I don't understand much. There are two definitions of $T_{a,b}(x)$. I don't understand what $i_m$ is. A "representation" is a set of ... but I don't know what set you are talking about. Is $T_{a,b}\colon \mathbb{Q}_2 \to \mathbb{Q}_2$ or is it suppose to be in $\mathbb{Q}_2[\![x]\!]$ ? The summation in $T_k$ is over $k$? Etc. I think this question is unclear.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I have simplified and much improved the terminology.  Is the question clear now?

Comment: @LSpice I have substantially simplified this question now. Maybe it is easier for you to help me now?

Comment: In the absence of quantifiers, the definitions are still far from clear.

Comment: @YCor does that edit resolve the quantifiers issue?  I thought it simpler without but try now.

Comment: @YCor if not fixed, would you please be so good to point to something which is not quantified?

Comment: $v_2(f_{1,2}(x)) = v_2(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_2$. The sum for $T_{1,2}$ cannot converge.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich $f_{1,2}(2)=2,4,8...\to0$

Comment: I don't know what you mean. $f_{1,2}(2)=6$, $f_{1,2}(6)=10$, ... and so $T_{1,2}$ does not converge for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich you are right, I had an error. The point is the 2-adic value of the additive part needs to match the 2-adic value of $x$. I'm sorry for the error.

Comment: I am giving up. My vote to close stands. Sorry. I just don't have the time to continue guessing what you don't seem to be able to write down properly.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I lack the reputation to comment, and the question is extremely hard to parse so I can’t be all that confident (silver lining: more space to ramble). To me it appears that if you fix up your definitions (I’m basing this more on your earlier edits) your transformation can be described much more simply in terms of looking at 2-adic expansions with varying choices of uniformizer and coefficients.

To be precise, if $a,b$ are 2-adic units, then any 2-adic number $x$ can be written in the form
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i (2a)^i$$
where $b_i$ is either $b$ or $0$. Then it seems like (big question mark) your transformation simply sends this $x$ to
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i 2^i$$
where $c_i$ is either $1$ when $b_i=b$, and otherwise remains $0$.

So it seems like the transformation corresponding to $1/a,1/b$ is the inverse you want.

Comment: Thank-you @ophelia for taking a look at my problem. I'll try that and see how I get on.

Comment: Ah, sadly on reflection I think this is close but not quite what I intended.  With the uniformizer the powers of $a$ climb with every digit.  But with the isometries I intended, the power of $b$ only climbs with every **nonzero** digit so they do not agree.  But thank-you for trying,